# how to store multiple values kind of output generated from for loop in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, flask

I was printing output in an iteration using a **for loop** in the following format.

`print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")`

But, for some reason, Now I have to print the whole output in a single variable.
How do I make it work ?
Do I have to use list ? If yes then how ?

Comment: `I have to print the whole output in a single variable` what does that mean?

Comment: I meant all the output that will going to be get from iteration of loop will store in a single variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting to assign your formatted string to a variable and print it

Example using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for `python>=3.6`

```
s = f'{fname} [{line_no},{index}] {line}'
print(s)
```

Or using [string.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting)

```
s = '{} [{},{}] {}'.format(fname, line_no, index, line)
print(s)
```

To collect all this in a string via a for loop, you can use a list to collect the strings, and join and print them outside the loop

```
#List to collect strings
li = []

#Iterate through for loop and add all strings to list
for foo in blah:
    s = f'{fname} [{line_no},{index}] {line}'
    li.append(s)

#Join list to string and print it
res = ' '.join(li)
print(res)
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandings.`print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")` This prints the output for each iteration. And I want to store all the output in a single variable. Thanks